# How to create a ClassBreakRenderer without data coming from Feature Layer?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I would like to create a ClassBreakRenderer to represent integer values. The symbols I am using are defined as PictureMarkerSymbols with JSON and they are just a filled blue circle with different sizes that were created with ArcMap 10.1 and published into ArcGIS Server. This is just to introduce the thing.

The problem is that in all the examples I see on the [ArcGIS Javascript API about Rendering](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm), the examples **do always** get the data from a **particular column** of a Feature Layer, but **my data do NOT come** from this data source: **they come from an array of integers in client side.** Just the symbol comes from the server-side, but not the integer value.

**Is there any way of "tricking" the constructor** of ClassBreakRenderer **in order to accept an array** *(or collection, dictionary, set, whatever)* of integers to be classified in symbols? There **should be "life"** a part of Feature Layers, isn't it?

Thanks for your help!

---

**EDIT**

The thing is that **my data source is an array** of integers like this:

```
var myArray = [15, 37, 47, 12, 125, 87, 36, 66, 10, 4, 18, 19, 23]
```

AND NOT:

```
var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3", {
          mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
          outFields: ["*"],
```

And in principle, the ClassBreakRenderer receives a column of that Feature Layer as:

```
var renderer = new esri.renderer.ClassBreaksRenderer(symbol, "POP07_SQMI");
```

But **I do NOT have that column "POP07_SQMI" I have an array called "myArray"** and my question is that if it is possible to use the array instead of the column name that I don't have. Because world should not be limited to the existence of feature layers to retrieve data from them.... :S

Comment: Your renderer has to reference an attribute field from your feature layer. You can define the breaks however you like, but the renderer uses the value from some field for each  feature out how to symbolize it. Are you sure you want a class breaks renderer and not a unique value renderer?

Answer (score 3):

In the newest versions of ArcGIS for JavaScript, you can use the `ClassBreaksRenderer` to render data coming from an array.  Instead of referencing a `FeatureLayer` column in the call to the `classBreaksRenderer` like this:

```
var renderer = new esri.renderer.ClassBreaksRenderer(symbol, "POP07_SQMI");
```

reference a call to a function, like this:

```
var renderer = new esri.renderer.ClassBreaksRenderer(null, myFunction());
```

You need to have the `myFunction()` function return a distinct number for each key value that you input into the `myFunction()` as an input parameter.  Basically you feed `myFunction()` an input parameter and return the number you want to classify that key to.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own class breaks renderer, specify your breaks using [addBreak](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/classbreaksrenderer.htm#addBreak), then apply your renderer to the feature layer using [setRenderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/featurelayer.htm#setRenderer). You'll probably want to create your feature layer with visible: false then call [show()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/layer.htm#show) once you apply the renderer.

Comment: But it turns out that I do NOT have a Feature Layer as a source for data. I have sth like: var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...]. Did I misunderstood you?

Comment: I think we misunderstood each other. I'm not clear on what you want to do. Can you edit your question and clarify what you're doing? What is the data source?